# Consume web service having Byte64 array as parameter with python Zeep

Tags: python, wsdl, zeep

I'm trying to consume a webservice with python Zeep that has a parameter of type xsd:base64Binary technical document specify type as: Byte[]

Errors are:
*urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''*
and on the reply I get: *Generic error "data at the root level is invalid.*

I can't find the correct way to do it.
My code is:

```
content=open(fileName,"r").read()
encodedContent = base64.b64encode(content.encode('ascii'))
myParameter=dict(param=dict(XMLFile=encodedContent))
client.service.SendFile(**myParameter)
```

thanks everyone for the comments.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

This is how the [built-in type](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/master/src/zeep/xsd/types/builtins.py) of Base64Binary looks like in zeep:

```
class Base64Binary(BuiltinType):
    accepted_types = [str]
    _default_qname = xsd_ns("base64Binary")

    @check_no_collection
    def xmlvalue(self, value):
        return base64.b64encode(value)

    def pythonvalue(self, value):
        return base64.b64decode(value)
```

As you can see, it's doing the encoding and decoding by itself. You don't need to encode the file content, you have to send it as it is and zeep will encode it before putting it on the wire.

Most likely this is causing the issue. When the message element is decoded, an array of bytes is expected but another base64 string is found there.